# gitlab CI/CD pipelines: how to search by execution date

Tags: gitlab-ci

Is it possible to search for pipeline by execution date?
Example, I need to fine results of pipelines that was executed at 2023-01-31.

I have look around of net, but could not find any suggestion how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know a GUI way, but you can use GitLab [Pipelines API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html) to search and filter pipelines programmatically.

Use `updated_after` or/and `updated_before` fields when requesting `GET /projects/:id/pipelines` API endpoint. Example from documentation without filtering:

```bash
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1/pipelines"
```

For full accepted parameters reference please follow the official documentation: [List project pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#list-project-pipelines).